# What is the date format for "2017-03-29 18:17:12+00"

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, date-format, date-formatting

I want to construct date "2017-03-29 18:17:12+00" but I am getting the following format while using the format,

```
public static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ";

2017-02-28 11:12:31+0000
```

I Need the format of "2017-03-29 18:17:12+00".

How to get this? what is the format?

Kindly provide your inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `X` intead of `Z` in your format string.

Answer (score 4):

Try `X` which is `ISO 8601 time zone`

```
public static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssX";
```

Comment: Close, but [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) is a standard defining textual formats for date-time strings. But actually, to comply with the standard this string must use a `T` in the middle rather than a SPACE. And a time zone is not involved here, only an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) of zero which means [UTC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) itself. A time zone is a `continent/region` such as `America/Montreal` which names a history of changes to the offset used by a particular region.

Answer (score 0):

If you use JDK 8 `java.time` API, you will get the desired format `(ISO 8601)` by default.

```
System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())); // 2017-05-26T16:20:42.821+05:30
```

Comment: Close! You’ve got a T in there that I didn’t see the OP asking for (of course s/he should use the modern classes nevertheless, they too can produce the string without the T).

Comment: To get rid of the T, either use `.replace('T', ' ')` on the string or use `.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssX")` on the `OffsetDateTime` (I haven’t tested neither).

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure to always use the ISO8601.

As shazin stated you can replace your Z with X to perform the accepting of a Date.

As addition I would suggest to use the OffsetDateTime API like this:

```
OffsetDateTime time = OffsetDateTime.parse( YOUR_DATE_STRING );
```

this will give you an OffsetDateTime object you can work with to the correct time-zone. Also if you want to convert the input to your local time zone or the UTC timezone you can use

```
time.atZoneSameInstant( ZoneId.systemDefault() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that not all time zones are shifted from UTC by an integral number of
hours. So when standards where created, nobody thought that there would
be a demand to print the time shift as only 2 digits.

And probably this is why "Z" as a time shift placeholder is converted to
"+" or "-" char, and just **four** digits.

I think, the solution is:

- generate the data/time string with 4 digit time shift part,
- cut off the last 2 digits.

But be aware that in some cases, e.g. Afghanistan (4h 30m)
or Central Australia (10h 30m) this 2-digit time shift will be inaccurate.

Comment: It’s viable, but for reasons you have explained nicely one should at least check that the last two digits are `00` before cutting them off.